# UIWebview loading html with large image files causes memory pressure app crash

Tags: objective-c, image, memory, uiwebview, crash

I am building an app that has several UIWebviews all displaying various content. While testing my app, I ran into an error that said the app was terminated due to memory pressure, and I checked the console, and sure enough I had received a memory warning. Upon further testing, I noticed that this only occurs when visiting a specific page. I noticed that this page contains 2 very large image file (both 5,184px × 3,456px), which is different from the other webpages (there are about 100 and this only happens on this one page), so I think that's where the bug is. Is there a way to get UIWebview to process this and present the page, or is there no hope?

This page also puts this image into a UIImageView of size 320x320, but I don't think this is the problem because the image shows up when I go to the page, but the app crashes when I scroll down the UIWebView

Comment: Create different sizes of the image. Have your html check screen size and use the appropriately sized image.